# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key '****'.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to do a dropdownlist of Student Enrollments at Student index page.

Student Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string studentEnrollment, string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            var students = studentService.GetAll();

            //var students = from s in studentService.GetAll()
            //               select s;

            var studentViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Student>, IEnumerable<StudentViewModel>>(students);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                       || s.FirstMidName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            }
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                    break;
                default:
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
            }

            List<Course> courses = new List<Course>();

            SelectList studentEnrollment = new SelectList(courses, "CourseID", "Title");

            ViewBag.Courses = studentEnrollment;

            //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(studentEnrollment))
            //    students = students.Where(m => m.Course.Title == studentEnrollment);

            int pageSize = 3;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

           return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Student", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)

        Enrollment: @Html.DropDownList("Course", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Courses, "Select Course")

        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
}
```

error at line:
Enrollment: @Html.DropDownList("Course", (IEnumerable)ViewBag.Courses, "Select Course")

What Im doing wrong?

Comment: Try to map in the View to SelectList and not to IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, also when SelectList inherits from IEnumerable<SelectListItem>. I googled it, and some told, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a lot of questions where people have had issues with the drop down list and it was because of the view bag.  Everything I have seen says you should try to avoid using ViewBag for drop downs.  What I would suggest instead is to put your list in your viewmodel.

```
Public List<SelectListItem> CourseList { get; set; }
```

I am not seeing in your code where you are populating your course list.  On your controller instead of setting the viewbag set this parameter.   Something like

```
foreach(var temp in CourseList){ //Course list being pulled from the database or wherever that data exists
    model.CourseList.Add(new SelectListItem{ Text = temp.Name, Value = temp.Value });
}
```

then on your view your drop down list would be changed to

```
@Html.DropDownList("Course", Model.CourseList, "Select Course")
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunately is still not working

Comment: can you post your changed code?  Let me know what errors you are getting and at what point

Comment: CS1061: "PagedList.IPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>" does not contain a definition for 'CourseList' and no extension method 'CourseList' accepting a first argument of type 'PagedList.IPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think Im something doing wrong I will post you changed code Im sure You will find a mistake.

Comment: foreach (var item in CourseList)
            { //Course list being pulled from the database or wherever that data exists
                students.Select(x => x.CourseList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Name, Value = item.Value }));
            }

Comment: .Name and .Value underline red colour

Comment: I don't know what the names of your fields are.  Item in this case is from your CourseList object so it will be coursename and courseid or whatever you have named those fields and you want in your drop down